# Rendered blender video stops at a frame when using speed control strip

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, effects

I am trying to render a video in blender video editing 2.93.3. I added an effect strip for speed control in order to make the video faster.

When I look at the video in blender, everything looks good, the whole video is played and at a faster speed. But when I render it, the result is the first part of the video at a faster speed, and then it stops at a frame after about half of the video and that frame is shown for the rest of the video.

This is what my video looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: sounds weird. can u provide blend file?

Comment: Yes! Can you download it here? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojTdqoVekk8gUw8v7eXyC_GdVIOiME5_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Chris could you see it?

Comment: i can't even see anything in preview...did you do file->external data->pack resources before uploading?

Comment: Ah, forgot that. Can you see it now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsI0wnvypqp6uMG7936cWqHCu-OKCQLw/view?usp=sharing @Chris?